# Getting web logs converted in CEF format in Kibana

Tags: logstash-grok

I have application logs in the below given format which i am indexing in elasticsearch. Now i want to get these logs into kibana in the CEF format. Is there any way to convert these logs into CEF format in kibana using the logstash filter?

Actual logs :

> Feb 16 17 12:53:46,174 ERROR net.sourceforge.stripes.tag.FormTag -
>   Could not locate an ActionBean that was bound to the URL
>   [/admin/Home.action]. Without an ActionBean class Stripes cannot
>   determine whether the ActionBean is a wizard or not. As a result
>   wizard behaviour will be disabled.

CEF format in which i wish to get the logs in Kibana:

> CEF:Version|Device Vendor|Device Product|Device Version|Signature
>   ID|Name|Severity|Extension.

A quick help is highly appreciable.

Thanks,
Shantanu.